To get NotificationManager... property vs method
I wrote a single class to handle notifications from 4 services.
I used method2 which works but I don't know if it's the most efficient
The best solution and why? Thank you !
public class Demo {
    private Context CONTEXT;
    private NotificationManager manager;

    public Demo(Context context) {
        CONTEXT = context;
        manager = getManager();
    }
    private NotificationManager getManager() {
        return (NotificationManager) CONTEXT.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    /*
    Solution 1
     */
    public void method1(){
        manager.notify(1, new Notification());
    }
    /*
    Solution 2
     */
    public void method2(){
        getManager().notify(1, new Notification());
    }
}

